# body does not cover full screen

Tags: html, css

```css
.box {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">

  </div>
</body>
```

I set the box margin-top to 100px, Why doesn't the body cover the full screen? The body acts as the div which has a margin top.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/_Dana/qek4c765/1/)

Comment: the result is exactly as it should be.... what is your real problem?

Comment: the reason is `margin-top:100px`. Try removing it: http://jsfiddle.net/qek4c765/3/

Comment: Why the body should cover the full screen?

Comment: The body **does** cover the fill screen. http://jsfiddle.net/qek4c765/4/

Comment: let add the border :)  https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/qek4c765/5/

Comment: @Lahori  I think the body does not have margin top,so it should start from top left. But the fact it has a margin top. I just gave margin top to box

Comment: @Xiaolong — There's nothing in the code in your question which would reveal any margin on the body element, so what does the code in the question have to do with it? (The body element has a default non-zero margin in all browsers, there's no reason to expect it to be zero, content that touches the viewport edge is hard to read).

Comment: Thanks a lot . I got it.

Answer (score 2):

try this code,

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't make any difference

Comment: it does... it removes 8px of body margin for me..

Comment: yeah, it always does @Quentin because body has a default margin which is 8px

Comment: Which makes no difference because adjacent vertical margins collapse through each other.

Answer (score -1):

The `<body>` tag refers his height assuming the contents height, not the viewport itself, why should indeed?
Adding something like this:

```
<body style="height: 100%">
```

changes the situation...